# How to use MagTek card reader device's sdk for android?

Tags: android, device, credit-card, reader

I am using magtek card reader audio uDynamo device and i am integrating sdk with my android application. But when i am trying to open device through openDevice() method. Application unfortunately stopped. Why its doing like this ?

This is what i am doing

```
            m_SCRA.setConnectionType(MTConnectionType.Audio);

            m_SCRA.setAddress(m_deviceAddress);

            m_connectionState = MTConnectionState.Connected;
            // here its stopping
            m_SCRA.openDevice();
```

Full source code

```
         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MTSCRA m_SCRA;
private Button btn;
private TextView txt;
private TextView txt1;
private TextView msg;
private TextView msg2;
private boolean m_startTransactionActionPending;
private boolean m_turnOffLEDPending;
private EditText Edit;
private AudioManager m_audioManager;
private int m_audioVolume;
private String m_deviceAddress;
private MTConnectionType m_connectionType;
private MTConnectionState m_connectionState = MTConnectionState.Disconnected;
private Handler m_scraHandler = new Handler(new SCRAHandlerCallback());

private class SCRAHandlerCallback implements Handler.Callback {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Alert Switch");
            alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();

            switch (msg.what)
            {

                case MTSCRAEvent.OnDeviceConnectionStateChanged:
                    OnDeviceStateChanged((MTConnectionState) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTSCRAEvent.OnCardDataStateChanged:
                    OnCardDataStateChanged((MTCardDataState) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTSCRAEvent.OnDataReceived:
                    OnCardDataReceived((IMTCardData) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTSCRAEvent.OnDeviceResponse:
                    OnDeviceResponse((String) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTEMVEvent.OnTransactionStatus:
                    OnTransactionStatus((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTEMVEvent.OnDisplayMessageRequest:
                    OnDisplayMessageRequest((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTEMVEvent.OnUserSelectionRequest:
                    OnUserSelectionRequest((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTEMVEvent.OnARQCReceived:
                    OnARQCReceived((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MTEMVEvent.OnTransactionResult:
                    OnTransactionResult((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;

                case MTEMVEvent.OnEMVCommandResult:
                    OnEMVCommandResult((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    break;

                case MTEMVEvent.OnDeviceExtendedResponse:
                    OnDeviceExtendedResponse((String) msg.obj);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return true;
    }
}
public void OnCardDataReceived(IMTCardData cardData)
{
    txt.setText(m_SCRA.getCardLast4());
}
protected void OnDeviceStateChanged(MTConnectionState deviceState)
{
    setState(deviceState);
    updateDisplay();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert ondevice state");
    alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();

    switch (deviceState)
    {
        case Disconnected:
            if (m_connectionType == MTConnectionType.Audio)
            {
                restoreVolume();
            }
            break;
        case Connected:
            if (m_connectionType == MTConnectionType.Audio)
            {
                setVolumeToMax();
            }
            clearMessage();
            clearMessage2();
            break;
        case Error:
            sendToDisplay("[Device State Error]");
            break;
        case Connecting:
            break;
        case Disconnecting:
            break;
    }
}
protected void OnCardDataStateChanged(MTCardDataState cardDataState)
{
    switch (cardDataState)
    {
        case DataNotReady:
            sendToDisplay("[Card Data Not Ready]");
            break;
        case DataReady:
            sendToDisplay("[Card Data Ready]");
            break;
        case DataError:
            sendToDisplay("[Card Data Error]");
            break;
    }

}
protected void OnDeviceResponse(String data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[Device Response]");

    sendToDisplay(data);

    if (m_startTransactionActionPending)
    {
        m_startTransactionActionPending = false;

        startTransaction();
    }
}

protected void OnTransactionStatus(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[Transaction Status]");

    //sendToDisplay(TLVParser.getHexString(data));
}

protected void OnDisplayMessageRequest(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[Display Message Request]");

    //String message = TLVParser.getTextString(data, 0);

    //sendToDisplay(message);

    //displayMessage(message);
}

protected void OnEMVCommandResult(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[EMV Command Result]");

    //sendToDisplay(TLVParser.getHexString(data));

    if (m_turnOffLEDPending)
    {
        m_turnOffLEDPending = false;

        setLED(false);
    }
}

protected void OnDeviceExtendedResponse(String data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[Device Extended Response]");

    sendToDisplay(data);
}
protected void OnUserSelectionRequest(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[User Selection Request]");

    //sendToDisplay(TLVParser.getHexString(data));

    //processSelectionRequest(data);
}
protected void OnARQCReceived(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[ARQC Received]");

    /*sendToDisplay(TLVParser.getHexString(data));

    List<HashMap<String, String>> parsedTLVList = TLVParser.parseEMVData(data, true, "");

    if (parsedTLVList != null)
    {
        String deviceSNString = TLVParser.getTagValue(parsedTLVList, "DFDF25");
        byte[] deviceSN = TLVParser.getByteArrayFromHexString(deviceSNString);

        sendToDisplay("SN Bytes=" + deviceSNString);
        sendToDisplay("SN String=" + TLVParser.getTextString(deviceSN, 2));

        boolean approved = true;

        if (mMainMenu != null)
        {
            approved = mMainMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_emv_approved).isChecked();
        }

        byte[] response = buildAcquirerResponse(deviceSN, approved);

        setAcquirerResponse(response);
    }*/
}
protected void OnTransactionResult(byte[] data)
{
    sendToDisplay("[Transaction Result]");

    //sendToDisplay(TLVParser.getHexString(data));

    /*if (data != null)
    {
        if (data.length > 0)
        {
            boolean signatureRequired = (data[0] != 0);

            int lenBatchData = data.length - 3;
            if (lenBatchData > 0)
            {
                byte[] batchData = new byte[lenBatchData];

                System.arraycopy(data, 3, batchData, 0, lenBatchData);

                sendToDisplay("(Parsed Batch Data)");

                List<HashMap<String, String>> parsedTLVList = TLVParser.parseEMVData(batchData, false, "");

                displayParsedTLV(parsedTLVList);

                String cidString = TLVParser.getTagValue(parsedTLVList, "9F27");
                byte[] cidValue = TLVParser.getByteArrayFromHexString(cidString);

                boolean approved = false;

                if (cidValue != null)
                {
                    if (cidValue.length > 0)
                    {
                        if ((cidValue[0] & (byte) 0x40) != 0)
                        {
                            approved = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (approved)
                {
                    if (signatureRequired)
                    {
                        displayMessage2("( Signature Required )");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        displayMessage2("( No Signature Required )");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setLED(false);*/
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = ( Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgtext1);
    msg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgtext2);
    Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


    //m_SCRA.setConnectionType(MTConnectionType.Audio);


   //if (! m_SCRA.isDeviceConnected())
    //{
    //      m_SCRA.openDevice();
    //}
    m_audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    m_SCRA = new MTSCRA(this, m_scraHandler);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            m_connectionType = MTConnectionType.Audio;

            m_SCRA.setConnectionType(MTConnectionType.Audio);


            m_SCRA.setAddress(m_deviceAddress);

            m_connectionState = MTConnectionState.Connected;
            m_SCRA.openDevice();
        }
    });

}
private void sendToDisplay(final String data)
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Edit.append(data + "\n");
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setState(MTConnectionState deviceState)
{
    m_connectionState = deviceState;
    updateDisplay();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private void updateDisplay()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (m_connectionState == MTConnectionState.Connected)
            {
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            }
            else if (m_connectionState == MTConnectionState.Connecting)
            {
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connecting);
            }
            else if (m_connectionState == MTConnectionState.Disconnecting)
            {
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnecting);
            }
            else if (m_connectionState == MTConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            }
        }
    });
}
private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            txt1.setText(resourceId);
        }
    });
}
private void restoreVolume()
{
    setVolume(m_audioVolume);
}
private void setVolumeToMax()
{
    saveVolume();
    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert volume max");
    alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();

    int volume = m_audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    setVolume(volume);
}
private void setVolume(int volume)
{
    m_audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
}

private void saveVolume()
{
    m_audioVolume = m_audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
private void clearMessage()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            msg.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private void clearMessage2()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            msg2.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public void startTransaction()
{
    if (m_SCRA != null)
    {
        byte timeLimit = 0x3C;
        //byte cardType = 0x02;  // Chip Only
        byte cardType = 0x03;  // MSR + Chip
        byte option = 0x00;
        byte[] amount = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00};
        byte transactionType = 0x00; // Purchase
        byte[] cashBack = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        byte[] currencyCode = new byte[] { 0x08, 0x40};
        byte reportingOption = 0x02;  // All Status Changes

        clearMessage();
        clearMessage2();

        int result = m_SCRA.startTransaction(timeLimit, cardType, option, amount, transactionType, cashBack, currencyCode, reportingOption);

        sendToDisplay("[Start Transaction] (Result=" + result + ")");
    }
}
public void setLED(boolean on)
{
    if (m_SCRA != null)
    {
        if (on)
        {
            m_SCRA.sendCommandToDevice(MTDeviceConstants.SCRA_DEVICE_COMMAND_STRING_SET_LED_ON);
        }
        else
        {
            m_SCRA.sendCommandToDevice(MTDeviceConstants.SCRA_DEVICE_COMMAND_STRING_SET_LED_OFF);
        }
    }
}  }
```

Comment: What error does it show in the Logcat ?

Comment: app unfortunately stopped working This error ..

Comment: no, error stacktrace in Log Monitor console

Comment: Logcat showing this 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: Magtek Audio Reader Communications Thread
                                                                                         Process: com.example.karanveer.cardreaderexample, PID: 28348
                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.

Comment: You are starting recording before Audio device is ready. look for a `prepare` method before starting recording

Comment: prepare method ??

Comment: If you are recording audio, here is the proper way to do so https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: this error also                                                                                               09-27 11:24:33.517 8529-8842/com.example.karanveer.cardreaderexample E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
09-27 11:24:33.520 8529-8842/com.example.karanveer.cardreaderexample E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
09-27 11:24:33.520 8529-8842/com.example.karanveer.cardreaderexample E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Comment: show us the source code.

Comment: see in question i added source code

Comment: I see no prob with the magtek, comment out your audiomanager code and try again

Comment: All audio manager code or only which is in onCreate method ??

Comment: try with all, then gradually step by step, this will help you find the culprit,

Comment: Ok Thanks i will try :)

Comment: Hello @MurtazaKhursheedHussain i have tried but this is not because of audio manager i think their is problem in handler class can you please tell me if there is or if you can ??

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. It turned out that I forgot audio recording runtime permission.

```
private void checkRecordPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                123);
    }
}
```